# How to find whether a string contains any of the special characters?

Tags: c#

I want to find whether a string contains any of the special characters like !,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,)....etc.

How can I do that without looping thorugh all the characters in the string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
  Regex RgxUrl = new Regex("[^a-z0-9]");
                    blnContainsSpecialCharacters = RgxUrl.IsMatch(stringToCheck);
```

Comment: this will accept `à`, is that a special character for the OP? (of course it's not, the OP already accepted the answer)

Answer (score 40):

Use [`String.IndexOfAny`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50.aspx):

```
private static readonly char[] SpecialChars = "!@#$%^&*()".ToCharArray();

...

int indexOf = text.IndexOfAny(SpecialChars);
if (indexOf == -1)
{
    // No special chars
}
```

Of course that will loop internally - but at least you don't have to do it in your code.

Comment: Hey Jon, how will you implement Mark's Byers thought?

Comment: @Manish: Given that you're likely to have a wide range of characters to whitelist, a regex is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of checking if a string contains "special characters" it is often better to check that all the characters in the string are "ordinary" characters, in other words use a whitelist instead of a blacklist. The reason is that there are a lot of characters that could be considered "special characters" and if you try to list them all you are bound to miss one.

So instead of doing what you asked it might be better to check for example that your string matches the regex `@"^\w+$"`, or whatever you need.

Comment: @Bubblewrap: I suggested using a regex with a whitelist. Is that not a valid answer to the question? The problem with the black list method is the bit where he writes 'etc...'. Computers can't guess what you mean, and writing a list of all special characters is IMHO the wrong way to approach this problem.

Comment: IMO it isn't. Without knowing the motivation behind the question, you can't really say that using a whitelist is a better (or even valid) alternative to using IndexOfAny. And the question was, as i read it, specifically about blacklists.

Comment: +1...nice thought and support your opinion in comparison with bubblewrap :)

Answer (score 9):

Linq is the new black.

```
string.Any(c => char.IsSymbol(c));
```

For IsSymbol(), valid symbols are members of [UnicodeCategory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory(v=vs.110).aspx).

- Letterlike symbols, which include a set of mathematical alphanumeric symbols as well as symbols such as ℅, №, and ™
- Number forms, such as subscripts and superscripts
- Mathematical operators and arrows
- Geometric symbols
- Technical symbols
- Braille patterns
- Dingbats

**Edit:**

This does not catch ALL characters. This may supplement:

```
string.Any(c => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c));
```

Comment: I dont think string has Any method in it, I guess you meant stringValue as string is a c# keyword

Comment: In C#, the string keyword is an alias for String, making String and string equivalent. And since a String object is a sequential collection of System.Char objects that represent a string, you can use Linq methods like Any() or IndexOf().

Comment: what you are saying is true if Any is used on the input string rather than the keyword "string"

Answer (score 5):

Here is a short solution to check for special chars using LINQ

```
private bool ContainsSpecialChars(string value)
{
        var list = new[] {"~", "`", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "+", "=", "\""};
        return list.Any(value.Contains);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to accomplish a different result. To create a method which returns the special character used to separate a determined string, say 1#4#5, to then use it to Split that same string.
Since the sistem I am maintaining is built by so many different people, and in some cases, I have no idea which is the pattern(Usually there's none), the following helped me a lot. And I cant vote up as yet.

```
public String Separator(){
      **String specialCharacters = "%!@#$#^&*()?/>.<:;\\|}]{[_~`+=-" +"\"";**
      char[] specialCharactersArray = specialCharacters.toCharArray();
      char[] a = entrada.toCharArray();
      for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
          for(int y=0; y < specialCharactersArray.length; i++){
              if(a[i] == specialCharactersArray[y]){
                  separator = String.valueOf(specialCharactersArray[y]);   
              }
          }
      }
      return separator;
    }
```

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

```
//apart from regex we can also use this
string input = Console.ReadLine();
            char[] a = input.ToCharArray();
            char[] b = new char[a.Length];
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!Char.IsLetterOrDigit(a[i]))
                {
                    b[count] = a[i];
                    count++;
                }
            }
            Array.Resize(ref b, count);
            foreach(var items in b)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(items);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
//it will display the special characters in the string input
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool HasSpecialCharacters(string str)
{
  string specialCharacters = @"%!@#$%^&*()?/>.<,:;'\|}]{[_~`+=-" +"\"";
  char[] specialCharactersArray = specialCharacters.ToCharArray();

  int index = str.IndexOfAny(specialCharactersArray);
  //index == -1 no special characters
  if (index == -1)
    return false;
  else
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Also...

```
foreach (char character in "some*!@#@!#string")
        {
            if(!Char.IsLetterOrDigit(character))
            {
                //It is a special character.
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def splchar(str):
splchar=("~", "`", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "+", "=")
for chr in splchar:
    if (chr in str):
        print("not accepted")
        break
else:
        print("accepted")
str="GeeksForGeeks"
```

splchar(str)

Answer (score -2):

Using PHP, you can try:

```
if (preg_match("[^A-Za-z0-9]", $yourString) {
  //DO WHATEVER
}
```

This will return TRUE if the string contains anything other than a letter or number.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not in C#, but still gave me the required regex. :)

Comment: @Manish: Well, that's *a* regex - but not one which matches the question exactly. If you'd said "I only want to include alphanumeric characters, and no accents etc" then that would have been a different matter.

Comment: @Jon, I mentioned that I want to find whether a string contains ANY OF the special chars or not....In your answer, I can't mention all the special characters present in the world..right?
hENCE, this serves the purpose... :)