# Total no of possible special characters can be used in C#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find whether a string contains any of the special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522933/how-to-find-whether-a-string-contains-any-of-the-special-characters)

Dear All,

simple question I have a string and I want to make sure that there are special characters (like # $ _ & %) in that string.How can we achieve this using C#

Thanks 
lokesh

Comment: Special by which definition? The C# spec? URLs? Format characters? what?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use String.IndexOfAny: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexofany.aspx

```
bool specialCharacterIsInString = myString.IndexOfAny(new char[]{'#', '$', '_', '&', '%'}) != -1;
```

Adjust the characters array so that contains the characters that you consider "special character" in your current context.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Linq and Char.IsLetterOrDigit:

```
bool hasSymbol = myString.Any(!char.IsLetterOrDigit(x));
```