# Multi-level validation for an Object in C#

Tags: c#, validation

I have a Console project reads inputs from CSV file and tries to save them to database.

For that, I created a class `Person` that maps a CSV row.

The CSV file has two columns `Name` and `Age`. `Person` class is like.

```
class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
}
```

So the list of all populated objects is `List<Person>`.

I have a new requirement to display **validation messages** to console before proceed with saving populated objects to database.

Validation has two levels: **Error** and **Warning**.

For example if `Name` property contains a special character, I have to display this message: "**Error**: Name contains special character"

In case `Name` properly contains a numeric character, I have to display only warning message: "**Warning**: Name contains numeric character"

I was thinking about using [DataAnnotation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141(v=vs.98).aspx) but I cannot see a way to add different levels (Error and Warning) to validation process. Also, I'm not sure if DataAnnotation fits only in Web Applications.

Is there a way to add some functionality to `Person` class to get this validation done for each property?

**NB: This is just an example to better understand the question, I have other rules for other properties.**

Answer (score 0):

You could change the Name field to a property, and incorporate this error checking into its setter.  For checking if the string contains special characters though, you will need to build an array of characters you want to look for and see if any of those match a character within the string.

An example can be found here.. [Special Character Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522933/how-to-find-whether-a-string-contains-any-of-the-special-characters)

```
class Person
{
  private static readonly char[] numbers = "0123456789".ToCharArray();
  private static readonly char[] specialChars = "!@#$%^&*()".ToCharArray();
  private string _name;
  public string Name 
  {
     set
     {
        if (Validate(value, "Name"))
          _name = value;         
     }
     get { return _name; }
  }
  public int age;

  private bool Validate(string input, string varName)
  {
     bool isValid = true;
     if (input.IndexOfAny(specialChars) != -1)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Error- " + varName + " contains a special character.");
        isValid = false;
     } 
     if (input.IndexOfAny(numbers) != -1)
        Console.WriteLine("Warning- " + varName + " contains a number.");
        //optionally set isValid = false if warnings warrant this
     return isValid;
  }
}
```

Any other strings your person class contains can be formatted with properties in this same way.

Answer (score 0):

1. add a public "validation" function inside `Person` - you will be able to call that function from outside the class
2. Use Regex class to search for digits.
3. define your own special characters inside an array and use `Contains()` method to check if the name contains special chars.
4. return aftermath using `enum` (one way to do that) and handle names that are not valid

here is a general idea for what you need (please see comments):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo();
        }

        private static void Foo()
        {
            // init new object
            Person p1 = new Person { age = 55, Name = "jonat8han" };
            Person p2 = new Person { age = 55, Name = "jonat#han" };
            Person p3 = new Person { age = 55, Name = "jonathan" };

            List<Person> p = new List<Person>();
            p.Add(p1);
            p.Add(p2);
            p.Add(p3);

            foreach (Person person in p)
            {

                if (person.IsValid() == Person.Validation.IsWarning)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(person.Name + " has digit...");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    // write here some logic to do somthing with this....
                }
                else if (person.IsValid() == Person.Validation.IsError)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(person.Name + " special char...");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    // write here some logic to do somthing with this....
                }
                else if (person.IsValid() == Person.Validation.IsErrorAndWarning)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(person.Name + " special char and digit...");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    // write here some logic to do somthing with this....
                }

                else
                {
                    // everything IsOk
                }
            }

        }

        class Person
        {
            public enum Validation
            {
                IsWarning = 0,
                IsError = 1,
                IsErrorAndWarning = 2,
                IsOk = 3
            }
            public string Name;
            public int age;

            public Validation IsValid()
            {
                if (IsError() && IsWarning())
                {
                    return Validation.IsErrorAndWarning;
                }
                else if (IsError())
                {
                    return Validation.IsError;
                }

                else if (IsWarning())
                {
                    return Validation.IsWarning;
                }

                else
                {
                    return Validation.IsOk;
                }

            }


            private bool IsWarning()
            {
                // check if there are digits...
                Regex reg = new Regex("\\d");
                if (reg.IsMatch(this.Name) == true)
                {
                    // there is digit 
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }

            private bool IsError()
            {
                string[] speacialChars = new string[] { "*", "&", ".", "^", "#", "@" }; // define here what is a special character for your needs
                foreach (Char c in this.Name)
                {
                    if (speacialChars.Contains(c.ToString()))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```